# is it too much to check database every half a second

Tags: php, ajax, database

So I'm making a chat app. I use ajax to check for new entry(message) in database every 0.5sec. If there is then display the message. Is that too much to ask the server? Im using a cheap shared hosting service. From my experience so far, half the time message is fast and smooth, the other time, especially during peak time, messages disappear and the ajax request fail half the time. Sometimes even connection to database itself comes back fail. I want to know if its me asking too much from the server or my server is bad I should consider changing. (or both)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 simple ways,

First is that using some cache mechanism like [Redis](https://redis.io/) cache to save last state of every user-chat and last received message id,date to get rid of checking db on every request.

Second way is using Web-Socket instead of client to server requests. In this method you establishing a connection between client and server then once a new message arrived you pushes the message to client directly.

If you want to resolve your problem without any external tool, My offer to you is the second way.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I would probably recommend going with Web Sockets, seems like it fits your use case.

Look into http://socketo.me/

That being said I would look into upgrading your hosting from a shared account if you are wanting your site to remain performant under a larger load.  Again really depends how many users you are trying to cater for.